# CoreData: removal of 'didSave' notification immediately after save: call. Too soon?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

```
-(void)someBackgroundTask {
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
   [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self coordinator]];

   // ...

   NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];

   [context save:&error];

   // safe?
   [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];

   // ...
}


// meanwhile on the main thread...
-(void)handleSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
   [[self context] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

Is is safe to remove the observer so soon after the call to `save:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you've received the notification you want, it's not too soon. But there are other problems with that code.

It doesn't make any sense to add an observer, trigger the notification, and then remove the observer. You might as well call the `handleSaveNotification` method directly instead of bothering with notifications. It would have the same effect with less work.

The reason for this is that **notifications are delivered synchronously on the thread they were posted on**. So if `someBackgroundTask` is actually running on a background thread or queue, `handleSaveNotification` will also run in the background. Using notifications like this doesn't make you cross threads. To do the merge on the main thread, you have a few options, including:

- Register for the notification using `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`. With that method you can tell the notification center which queue to use. Make sure to save a reference to the object this method returns-- you'll need it later to remove the observer.
- Call the merge method directly, but in that method use `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to move the merge over to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I checked by logging `[thread description]` at each point and you're right (of course). So I'm using your latter. And I have logged a suggestion with Apple to improve their CoreData docs, which on this point are not clear at best. Now to the rest of my question: am I not setting up a race between the main thread and this background thread?

Comment: The "did save" notification will be posted before the call to `save:` returns, so you can remove the observer immediately afterward. It would still be simpler and cleaner to just call the merge method directly without using the notification.